# By default how to set "zoom in" to image instead of "fit to screen" in iviewer?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/asJpT/11/)**

I have following code in iviewer. here i want to show the image to be filled in whole grey box.

**HTML:**

```
<div id="viewer" class="viewer"></div>
```

**JS:**

```
  var $ = jQuery;
  $(document).ready(function () {
      var iv1 = $("#viewer").iviewer({
          src: "http://test.dpetroff.ru/jquery.iviewer/test/test_image.jpg",
          update_on_resize: false,
          zoom_animation: false,
          mousewheel: false,
          onMouseMove: function (ev, coords) {},
          onStartDrag: function (ev, coords) {
              return false;
          }, //this image will not be dragged
          onDrag: function (ev, coords) {}
      });

      $("#in").click(function () {
          iv1.iviewer('zoom_by', 1);
      });
      $("#out").click(function () {
          iv1.iviewer('zoom_by', -1);
      });
      $("#fit").click(function () {
          iv1.iviewer('fit');
      });
      $("#orig").click(function () {
          iv1.iviewer('set_zoom', 100);
      });
      $("#update").click(function () {
          iv1.iviewer('update_container_info');
      });
  });
```

Does anyone have idea for how to do that?

Comment: Are you looking for something like this? [fiddle updated](http://jsfiddle.net/asJpT/12/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this callback to your `iviewer` initialization:

```
onFinishLoad: function () {
    iv1.iviewer('zoom_by', 1);
}
```

Fiddle updated [here](http://jsfiddle.net/asJpT/12/).